# Template driven form validation inside second ngb-tab

Tags: angular, angular8

I am facing an issue with template driven form validation inside of `ngb-tab`.

I want to subscribe to validity changes of my form which is inside an ngb-tab as shown bellow:

```html
 <ngb-tab title="someTitle" id="tab-other">
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>
      <form class="animated fadeIn" #tranferInitForm="ngForm">
...
        <div class="input-group">
              <input name="benName" type="text" class="form-control" id="benName" #benName='ngModel'
                [(ngModel)]="options.benName" required [pattern]="inputPattern" maxlength="70">
              <label>some label</label>
            </div>
...
            <button class="btn btn-primary"
              [disabled]="!tranferInitForm.valid"
              (click)="onClick()">next step</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

and check the validity of the input inside a button `[disabled]="!tranferInitForm.valid"`

Should this be enough?

After that i tried adding in my component:

```js
@ViewChild('tranferInitForm', { static: true }) tranferInitForm;
ngOnInit() {
    this.tranferInitForm.statusChanges.subscribe(validity => {
      switch (validity) {
        case 'VALID':
          if (this._formValid) { return; }
          this._formValid = true;
          break;
        case 'INVALID':
          if (!this._formValid) { return; }
          this._formValid = false;
          break;
      }
    });
}
```

Which throws an error in the first run

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusChanges' of undefined

but working after that. I suppose because the form is inside the tab.

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you tried doing the same inside `ngAfterViewInit` and not `ngOnInit` ?

Comment: @callback Yes i have tried with AfterViewInit with the same result ```ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusChanges' of undefined```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the tab content isn't showed when component is loaded and which results in an undefined template reference.
You need to set static flag to false to have dynamic queries for view child elements and wait until the form tab become active to access it's reference.

There is two approches to achieve this :

1/ The simple approach is to use a reactive from so you can implement the required logic after form creation.

2/ listen to tabChange event and check if the nextId is your form tab id (tab-other in your case) and then access to the form reference after some delay because tabChange event is emitted **before the tab change happens** :

html

```
<ngb-tabset (tabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
```

ts

...

subscription : Subscription ;

...

```
onTabChange(event) {
    if (event.nextId === "tab-other" && !this.subscription) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.subscription = this.tranferInitForm.statusChanges.subscribe(
          validity => {
            switch (validity) {
              case "VALID":
                if (this._formValid) {
                  return;
                }
                this._formValid = true;
                break;
              case "INVALID":
                if (!this._formValid) {
                  return;
                }
                this._formValid = false;
                break;
            }
          }
        );
      }, 100);
    }
  }
```

Comment: how is your answer different from my comment?

Comment: static flag should be set to false to have dynamic queries for view child elements, the problem is because the tab content isn't showed when component is loaded and which results in an undefined template reference